# R melt and aggregate

Tags: r, aggregation

I have data of the type:

```
    sample   X   Y   Z
    A
    B
    A
    C
    ...
```

Where multiple measurements of A, B and C exist and each measurement is characterized by some parameters x,y,z, etc.

I want to get the mean and average of x,y,z  over each sample
like this

```
    sample   variable   Avg      SE
    A         x       mean(x)   ... 
    A         y       mean(y)   ... 
    A         z       mean(z)   ... 
    ...
```

Comment: This [blog post](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/) has an example of estimating the standard errors per group. See also this [CV question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/50623/1036) using linear regression to estimate the standard errors.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `dplyr`? You can dissect your data according to any group you want and then return summarized results.

```
mydf <- data.frame(sample = sample(LETTERS[1:4], size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   variable = runif(100))

library(dplyr)
mydf %.% group_by(sample) %.% 
  summarize(mean = mean(variable), 
            sd = sd(variable), 
            se = mean(variable) + (sd/sqrt(n())))

Source: local data frame [4 x 4]

  sample      mean        sd        se
1      A 0.4666366 0.2705698 0.5218665
2      B 0.4128302 0.2710152 0.4615059
3      C 0.5055496 0.2569661 0.5616242
4      D 0.5132356 0.2795494 0.5702984
```